# Unit testing method that uses ServerManager .net C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, iis

How would you test such method that uses ServerManager. Obviously you can't mock ServerManager. And this method is void. Is there a workaround? Should one event test such method? Thanks!

```
 public void AppPoolRemoval(string poolName)
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var oldPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[poolName];
            if (oldPool != null)
            {
                oldPool.Delete();
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: we decided on creating a dum wrapper around ServerManager with an interface to be able to unit test it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to unit test this code in isolation. You'd better write an integration test for it where you would have some IIS instance to test it on.

You could abstract this logic behind an interface:

```
public interface IWebServer
{
    void AppPoolRemoval(string poolName);
}
```

and then unit test in isolation the code that depends on this. But the actual implementation which is tied to a real `ServerManager` cannot be unit tested.

Comment: Ok. Seems that there is really no sane way to unit test such method. Thanks.